# Java Android : Comparator gets OutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, comparator

I'm not really an expert and can't figure out why is it going off bounds

```
public class ParticipantIndexComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    final List<Participant> participants;       
    public ParticipantIndexComparator(ArrayList<Integer> numbersToSort) {
        Log.d("MyLog","numbersToSort.size=" + numbersToSort.size());

        participants = new ArrayList<Participant>();

        for (int i=0;i<numbersToSort.size();i++) {     
            participants.add(i, competition.participant.get(numbersToSort.get(i)));
            participants.get(i).comparator = numbersToSort.get(i);
        }

        Log.d("MyLog","participants.size="+participants.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        Log.d("MyLog","in compare: participants.size=" + participants.size() + "i1=" + i1 + " i2=" + i2);
        long l1 = participants.get(i1).kpTime.get(kpSelected); 
        long l2 = participants.get(i2).kpTime.get(kpSelected);
        return Long.valueOf(l1).compareTo(Long.valueOf(l2));
    }
}
```

well , my first Log shows me `participants.size=8.`
Second Log shows me `participants.size=8.`
third Log shows me `participants.size=8, i1=13 i2=14.`

Why??? Why is it 13 and 14 when I checked size at every step and it's always 8 - I can't understand. I'm not an expert and can't figure out this myself

here is stacktrace :

```
11-24 02:41:23.612: E/AndroidRuntime(4802): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 14, size is 8
11-24 02:41:23.612: E/AndroidRuntime(4802):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
11-24 02:41:23.612: E/AndroidRuntime(4802):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
11-24 02:41:23.612: E/AndroidRuntime(4802):     at ru.maximhasanov.skitimer.FinalProtocolActivity$ParticipantIndexComparator.compare(FinalProtocolActivity.java:311)
11-24 02:41:23.612: E/AndroidRuntime(4802):     at ru.maximhasanov.skitimer.FinalProtocolActivity$ParticipantIndexComparator.compare(FinalProtocolActivity.java:1)
11-24 02:41:23.612: E/AndroidRuntime(4802):     at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:320)
11-24 02:41:23.612: E/AndroidRuntime(4802):     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:185)
11-24 02:41:23.612: E/AndroidRuntime(4802):     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
11-24 02:41:23.612: E/AndroidRuntime(4802):     at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:2038)
11-24 02:41:23.612: E/AndroidRuntime(4802):     at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1891)
11-24 02:41:23.612: E/AndroidRuntime(4802):     at ru.maximhasanov.skitimer.FinalProtocolActivity.sortNumbers(FinalProtocolActivity.java:213)
```

Comment: Could you pleasy clarify your Log entries. How is it possible that your first log entry is `participants.size=8.` if your first log string is `numbersToSort.size=`? You should debug step by step to identify when your code stops doing what it should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm gonna give this a shot. I think I kinda have a grasp on your situation.

As I said in my comment, I am thinking that `numbersToSort` holds a list of the numbers (essentially indexes) of a subset of `competition.participant` that you want to sort by a specific `kpTime`.

If this is correct, then the reason you're getting the `OutOfBoundsException` is because your `numbersToSort` contains numbers (which are indexes) that are greater than the size of `participants`, as `participants` is a subset of a bigger list.

I believe what you should do is create your `ArrayList<Participant> participants` in the  `sortNumbers` method of `FinalProtocolActivity`, and then call `Collections.sort()` on it with the following `Comparator`:

```
public class ParticipantIndexComparator implements Comparator<Participant>
{
    public int compare(Participant p1, Participant p2)
    {
        Long time1 = p1.kpTime.get(kpSelected);
        Long time2 = p2.kpTime.get(kpSelected);
        return Long.valueOf(time1).compareTo(time2);
    }
}
```

Comment: well ,thanx, it worked. I had to sort my ArrayList of indexes to ArrayList of objects that kept time values which needed to be sorted. So I stored an extra value of initial indexes into my objects, sorted objects as you proposed and made another ArrayList of indexes which I took from that extra value:))) This is a crazy scheme but evrything works now. :) Well, still I can't understand why it the first place 13th and 14th index were taken..

Answer (score 1):

As you explained,Your `participants` `size` is **8** but You are trying to get **13th** and **14th** element. How is it Possible. Here your Problem.

Comment: yes, but where from does theese 13 and 14 numbers come from?? I can't understand from my code I enclosed here - how possibly comparator could take 13 and 14th element?